# Redux Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my redux project for shopping app. I have four products. First two are being adding to the cart but adding  rest two is throwing an error, saying the price is not defined . This is so confusing
first two products are being added to the cart but the rest two is showing this error >>

MY Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
push../src/reducers/basketReducer.js.__webpack_exports__.default
C:/Users/pukar/Desktop/shopping-cart/src/reducers/basketReducer.js:43
  40 | // console.log(addQuantity)  
  41 | return {
  42 |   basketNumbers: state.basketNumbers + 1,
> 43 |   cartCost : state.cartCost + state.products[action.payload].price,
     | ^  44 |   products: {
  45 |       ...state.products,
  46 |       [action.payload] : addQuantity
```

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import basketReducer from './basketReducer'

export default  combineReducers({
   basketState : basketReducer
});
```

basketReducer.js

```
import { ADD_PRODUCTS_BASKET, GET_NUMBERS_BASKET } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    basketNumbers : 0,
    cartCost: 0,
    products: {
        Makeup : {
            name: "Make Up",
            price: 10.03,
            numbers: 0,
            inCart: false
        },
        Brushes : {
            name: "Brushes",
            price: 15.03,
            numbers: 0,
            inCart: false
        },
         NailPolish : {
            name: "NailPolish",
            price: 5.00,
            numbers: 0,
            inCart: false
        },
        EyeLiner : {
            name: "Eye Liner",
            price: 25.03,
            numbers: 0,
            inCart: false
        }
    }
}

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_PRODUCTS_BASKET :
        let addQuantity = {...state.products[action.payload]}
        addQuantity.numbers += 1;
        addQuantity.inCart = true
        // console.log(addQuantity)  
        return {
          basketNumbers: state.basketNumbers + 1,
          cartCost : state.cartCost + state.products[action.payload].price,
          products: {
              ...state.products,
              [action.payload] : addQuantity
            }
        }
    case GET_NUMBERS_BASKET :
        return {
            ...state
        }    
    default: 
    return state;
} 
}
```

cart.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const Cart = ({basketProps}) => {
    console.log(basketProps)


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Ths is the cart page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    basketProps : state.basketState
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps ) (Cart)
```

addAction.js

```
import {ADD_PRODUCTS_BASKET} from './types'

export const addBasket = (productName) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        console.log("Adding to Basket");
        console.log("Product: ", productName);
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_PRODUCTS_BASKET,
            payload: productName
        })
    }
}
```

home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import p1 from '../images/1.jpeg';
import p2 from '../images/2.jpeg';
import p3 from '../images/3.jpeg';
import p4 from '../images/4.jpg';

import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {addBasket} from '../actions/addAction'

const Home = (props) => {
 console.log(props);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='image'>
        <img src={p1} alt='Loading...' />
        <h3>Makeup</h3>
        <h3>$10.03</h3>
        <a onClick={() => props.addBasket('Makeup')} className='addToCart cart1' href='#'>
          Add to Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className='image'>
        <img src={p2} alt='Loading...' />
        <h3>Brushes</h3>
        <h3>$15.03</h3>
        <a onClick={() => props.addBasket('Brushes')}  className='addToCart cart2' href='#'>
          Add to Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className='image'>
        <img src={p3} alt='Loading...' />
        <h3>Nail polish</h3>
        <h3>$5.00</h3>
        <a onClick={() => props.addBasket('Nailpolish')}  className='addToCart cart3' href='#'>
          Add to Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className='image'>
        <img src={p4} alt='Loading...' />
        <h3>Eye Liner</h3>
        <h3>$25.03</h3>
        <a onClick={() => props.addBasket('Eye Liner')}  className='addToCart cart4' href='#'>
          Add to Cart
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(null, {addBasket}) (Home);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple error.

Your item (name of property in object `products`) in the initial redux state is `NailPolish`, but you are calling `props.addBasket('Nailpolish')` - with lower case 'p'.

Try to call `props.addBasket('NailPolish')`

The fourth item has a similar problem, an item in the redux state is `EyeLiner`, but you are calling `props.addBasket('Eye Liner')` - with whitespace in its name.

Try to call `props.addBasket('EyeLiner')`.

---

I strongly suggest to name all object properties in any object map (as your `products` is) with camelCase, e.g. `nailPolish`, `eyeLiner`.